# Application doesn't resume downloading after connection loss in Android emulator

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I have the following code which just reads bytes from a connection:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    val conn = URL("https://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu-releases/20.04.2.0/ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso").openConnection()
    val stream = conn.getInputStream()
    val byteBufferSize = 1024 * 100
    val buffer = ByteArray(byteBufferSize)
    do {
        val read = stream.read(buffer)
        println(read)
    } while (read != -1)
}.join()
```

When in the middle of reading I disconnect from the Internet, it stops reading and consequentially printing the number of bytes. Then I connect to the Internet it resumes downloading. I have the described behavior under JVM (non-Android).

When I try to run the same code in an Android emulator, disconnect (enable Airplane mode) and then connect to the Internet it doesn't resume downloading or maybe doesn't print to the console anymore.

What would cause such behavior under Android and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not very reliable code when it comes to resuminig downloads after network reset. for example

1. what happens if network is gone for too long that it causes `SocketTimeoutException`, I don't see any exception handling and resume logic in that case
2. What happens if server closes the connection due to some network issue or any issue on the server itself

I suggest you instead use the [`DownloadManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager), which is specifically designed to handle such scenarios automatically, from the docs

> The download manager is a system service that handles long-running
> HTTP downloads. Clients may request that a URI be downloaded to a
> particular destination file. The download manager will conduct the
> download in the background, taking care of HTTP interactions and
> retrying downloads after failures or across connectivity changes and
> system reboots.

You can use it as

```
fun startDownload() {
    val downloadManager = getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
    val uri = Uri.parse("https://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu-releases/20.04.2.0/ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso")
        
    /* Give permissions and handle the android 10+ storage access restrictions */
    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).mkdirs()
        
    downloadManager.enqueue(DownloadManager.Request(uri)
            .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or
                                    DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(true)
            .setTitle("Ubuntu")
            .setDescription("Latest Ubuntu")
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso"))
}
```

there are many other configuration options available, you can check out [this demo project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Internet/Download)

Comment: I am not really interested in advice about the best practices and robust solutions. I just wanna know why the behavior is different.